# accommodating (as in "Thanks for being so accommodating")

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

If someone has been very kind in adjusting their schedule and making sacrifices to help you, in English you might say, "Thanks for being so accommodating!"

What is the most natural translation of this phrase into Spanish? Looking up "accommodating" in an online Spanish/English dictionary yields no less than 18 possible translations, and I'm not sure which would fit best with this sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mmmm... that's a tricky one. I can't really think of a direct translation for the "*accommodating*" word. The term *[acomodaticio](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=acomodaticio)* does exist in Spanish, but sounds too "learned" or "elevated" to say in a regular conversation (at least to me).

For the case you're describing, I (Spaniard guy) would go with something like:

> Muchas gracias por adaptarte a mi[s] horario[s].

Someone asked the same question in [Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2308413&p=11586145#post11586145). The last answer (the one the link points to) is the best one in my opinion.

EDIT:

As [kelmer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/625/kelmer) pointed out in his comment, another fairly common expression you can use is:

> Gracias por ser tan flexible

This expression goes pretty well when talking about schedules.

Comment: "Gracias por ser tan flexible" would also be a possible translation.

Comment: Exactly, in Spain I would use one of those sentences expressing that, but as I think you want to say it in America, you could go for "acomedido" as Sergio Romero says in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The most natural, I believe, would be "acomedido".

> Gracias por ser tan acomedido.

Comment: I have never heard "acomedido" in Spain (but thanks for teaching me a new word). Where is it "most natural"?

Comment: @CesarGon: My mohter used it all the time, that's why I thought it was the most natural. We are from Mexico. I actually verified its existence in REA before posting: http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=acomedido

Comment: @SergioRomero yes, RAE says it's used in America, that's why we haven't heard it en este lado del charco :P

Comment: "No te acomides en nada."

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the verb "apoyar"

*Gracias por apoyarme*

Comment: Because it doesn't mean that.